# Translate animation not moving smoothly

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, translate-animation

I am trying to make a card game, I use translate animation to move the cards when user plays. It came to my notice that the animation works smoothly for device with higher android versions and performs poorly and Jacky on android 5.0 down. How can I make the animation moves smoothly on all devices? Below is my method used for move the cards.

```
public void  Move_Card_To_PlayArea(){
        Move_Card_Animation =new TranslateAnimation(0, (float) move_card_getX,0,(float) move_card_getY);
        Move_Card_Animation.setDuration(share_card_speed);
        Move_Card_Animation.setFillAfter(false);
        Move_Card_Animation.setAnimationListener(new Move_Card_Anim());
    }
```

Comment: What do you do in `Move_Card_Anim`?

Comment: I process the action to be taken which is determined by the card played.